# Restructuring to avoid accessing components in models

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Continuing to work on my port of a CakePHP 1.3 app to 3.0, and have run into another issue. I have a number of areas where functionality varies based on certain settings, and I have previously used a modular component approach. For example, Leagues can have round-robin, ladder or tournament scheduling. This impacts on the scheduling algorithm itself, such that there are different settings required to configure each type, but also dictates the way standings are rendered, ties are broken, etc. (This is just one of 10 areas where I have something similar, though not all of these suffer from the problem below.)

My solution to this in the past was to create a LeagueComponent with a base implementation, and then extend that class as LeagueRoundRobinComponent, LeagueLadderComponent and LeagueTournamentComponent. When controllers need to do anything algorithm-specific, they check the schedule_type field in the leagues table, create the appropriate component, and call functions in it. This still works just fine.

I mentioned that this also affects views. The old solution for this was to pass the league component object from the controller to the view via `$this->set`. The view can then query it for various functionality. This is admittedly a bit kludgy, but the obvious alternative seems to be extracting all the info the view might require and setting it all individually, which doesn't seem to me to be a lot better. If there's a better option, I'm open to it, but I'm not overly concerned about this at the moment.

The problem I've encountered is when tables need to get some of that component info. The issue at hand is when I am saving my add/edit form and need to deal with the custom settings. In order to be as flexible as possible for the future, I don't have all of these possible setting fields represented in the database, but rather serialize them into a single "custom" column. (Reading this all works quite nicely with a custom constructor and getters.) I had previously done this by loading the component from the beforeSave function in the League model, calling the function that returns the list of schedule-specific settings, extracting those values and serializing them. But with the changes to component access in 3.0, it seems I can no longer create the component in my new beforeMarshal function.

I suppose the controller could "pass" the component to the table by setting it as a property, but that feels like a major kludge, and there must be a better way. It doesn't seem like extending the table class is a good solution, because that would horribly complicate associations. I don't think that [custom types](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#adding-custom-database-types) are the solution, as I don't see how they'd access a component either. I'm leaning towards passing just the list of fields from the controller to the model, that's more of a "configuration" method. Speaking of configuration, I suppose it could all just go into the central Configure data store, but that's always felt to me like somewhere that you only put "small" data. I'm wondering if there's a better design pattern I could follow that would let the table continue to take care of these implementation details on its own without the controller needing to get involved; if at some point I decide to change from the serialized method to adding all of the possible columns, it would be nice to have those changes restricted to the table class.

Oh, and keep in mind that this list of custom settings is needed in both a view and the table, so whatever solution is proposed will ideally provide a way for both of them to access it, rather than requiring duplication of code.

Comment: Thinking about it more, it seems like "components" may be entirely the wrong solution here. They often deal with models internally, so it was convenient in the past to make them components, and they can get to models through `$this->controller->...`, but that's easily worked around now. I'll look at how much they really use the controllers that create them, and maybe it will be best to move them off to the "library" area instead.

Comment: ...and now I'm reading about [events](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html) and thinking that may be a solution for at least some of my "components". Though that would be a more substantial refactoring than what I was hoping for at this point.